# increase size of masked object cv2

Tags: python, opencv

i am trying to find some objects in an image.

i mask the areas in the image with a color threshold like this

```
def find_color_object(img, lower_bound, upper_bound):
    # Convert BGR to HSV
    hsv_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    # define limits
    low = np.array(lower_bound)
    up = np.array(upper_bound)
    # create a mask and return it
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv_img, low, up) 
    return mask
```

and it works fine on some random images.

in the final image the objects are very small. is there any way to encrease the masked objects without increasing the actual size of the image

Comment: how about [dilate](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html) from opencv? this should be applied to the mask. When you use the mask, the object will be larger... is this what you meant?

Comment: i think that was just it. Thanks